# An alternative for style="display:none"

Tags: javascript

In our project we are creating tables using JavaScript and displaying data in that table using xsl. we are getting data from backend through copybook.

Based on one value we are displaying, we have one column header in the table. If that value is *yes* then that column will come. While displaying data in that column we did not check any condition, just we are using `style="display:none"`. If that column comes then data is visible otherwise data is hidden. But when data is vible and when we click on one of the column names columns are shifting to left and data was hiding because of `style="display:none"`.

Is there anything that works similarly to `style="display:none"` such that when a column comes then it shows the data otherwise it hides the data?

I have tried with 'style="visible:hidden", it does not work. Whether the column came or not it is consuming space beacuse of that columns are shifing to right.

**style="display:none" is working properly means when column comes then only it is showing data otherwise it is hiding the data **. where as visibility:hidden is conusimg space.

Comment: try `style="visibility:hidden"`

Comment: `visibility` will still consume space. Why would you avoid `display:none` in the first place :(. Maybe you can try `width: 0; height: 0, display: block`.

Comment: Could you possibly make a Fiddle or something out of this?

Answer (score -1):

Use visibility instead:

```
style="visibility:hidden"
```

Comment: Its not the same. One (`display: none`) removes the element from the flow of the view while (`visibility: hidden`) hides it from the view

Comment: yes, visibility changing won't cause the shifting of columns as display:none does.